# Wildcard on mv folder destination

Tags: bash, shell, wildcard, move

I'm writing a small piece of code that checks for .mov files in a specific folder over 4gb and writes it to a log.txt file by name (without an extension). I'm then reading the names into a while loop line by line which signals some archiving and copying commands.

Consider a file named abcdefg.mov (new) and a corresponding folder somewhere else named abcdefg_20180525 (<-*underscore timestamp) that also contains a file named abcedfg.mov (old).

When reading in the filename from the log.txt, I strip the extension to store the variable "abcdefg" ($in1) and i'm using that variable to locate a folder elsewhere that *contains* that matching string at the beginning.

My problem is with how the mv command seems to support a wild card in the "source" string, but not in the "destination" string.

For example i can write;

```
mv -f /Volumes/Myshare/SourceVideo/$in1*/$in1.mov /Volumes/Myshare/Archive
```

However a wildcard on the destination doesn't work in the same way. For example;

```
mv -f /Volumes/Myshare/Processed/$in1.mov Volumes/Myshare/SourceVideo/$in1*/$in1.mov
```

Is there an easy fix here that doesn't involve using another method?

Cheers for any help.

Comment: A wildcard in the destination would be a real craps-shoot. How could you ever be sure where the file would end up?

Comment: Yeah, i could see where in certain situations it would be an issue, but i know in my case the basename is always going to be unique, no chance of there being a 100% match. Its just a temp location so there is only like 35-50 folders in there at a time...

Answer (score 1):

`mv` accepts a single destination path. Suppose that `$in1` is `abcdfg`, and that `$in1*` expands to  `abcdefg_20180525` and `abcdefg_20180526`. Then the  command

```
mv -f /dir1/$in1 /dir2/$in1*/$in1.mov
```

will be equivalent to:

```
mv -f /dir1/abcdefg.mov /dir2/abcdefg_20180526/abcdefg.mov
mv -f /dir1/abcdefg.mov /dir2/abcdefg_20180526/abcdefg.mov
mv -f /dir2/abcdefg_20180525/abcdefg.mov /dir2/abcdefg_20180526/abcdefg.mov
```

Moreover, because the destination file is the same in all three cases, the first two files will be overwritten by the third.

Comment: Yeah, definitely see where it could be a problem but 100% certain it would never be a problem (in my scenario) because the filenames are all unique and the repository in only temporary, constantly being flushed as new folders move in. I'm just surprised that its limited in this way, should be able to code based on understanding the risks involved and use best judgement, not be limited because in certain circumstances it might go wrong...

Answer (score 0):

You should create a precise list and do a precise copy instead of using wild cards.

This is what I would probably do, generate a list of results in a file with FULL path information, then read those results in another function. I could have used arrays but I wanted to keep it simple. At the bottom of this script is a function call to scan for files of EXT mp4 (case insensitive) then writes the results to a file in tmp. then the script reads the results from that file in another function and performs some operation (mv etc.). Note, if functions are confusing , you can just remove the function name { }  and name calls and it becomes a normal script again. functions are really handy, learn to love them!

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
readonly SIZE_CHECK_LIMIT_MB="10M"
readonly FOLDER="/tmp"
readonly DESTINATION_FOLDER="/tmp/archive"
readonly SAVE_LIST_FILE="/tmp/$(basename $0)-save-list.txt"
readonly EXT="mp4"
readonly CASE="-iname"  #change to -name for exact ext type upper/lower

function find_files_too_large() {

    > ${SAVE_LIST_FILE}
   find "${FOLDER}" -maxdepth 1 -type f "${CASE}" "*.${EXT}" -size +${SIZE_CHECK_LIMIT_MB} -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' line ; do
        echo "FOUND => $line"
        echo "$line" >> ${SAVE_LIST_FILE}
    done

}

function archive_large_files() {

    local read_file="${SAVE_LIST_FILE}"
    local write_folder="$DESTINATION_FOLDER"

    if [ ! -s "${read_file}" ]  || [ ! -f "${read_file}" ] ;then
        echo "No work to be done ... "
        return
    fi

    while IFS= read -r line ;do
        echo "mv $line $write_folder" ;sleep 1
    done < "${read_file}"

}

# MAIN (this is where the script starts) We just call two functions.
find_files_too_large
archive_large_files
```

Answer (score 0):

it might be easier, i think, to change the filenames to the folder name initially. So abcdefg.mov would be abcdefg_timestamp.mov. I can always strip the timestamp from the filename easy enough after its copied to the right location. I was hoping i had a small syntax issue but i think there is no easy way of doing what i thought i could...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have a basic misunderstanding of how wildcards work here. The `mv` command doesn't support wildcards *at all*; the shell expands all wildcards into lists of matching files before they get passed to the `mv` command as wildcards. Furthermore, the `mv` command doesn't know if the list of arguments it got came from wildcards or not, and the shell doesn't know anything about what the command is going to do with them. For instance, if you run the command `grep *`, the `grep` command just gets a list of names of files in the current directory as arguments, and will treat the first of them as a regex pattern ('cause that's what the first argument to `grep` is) to search the rest of the files for. If you ran `mv *` (note: don't do this!), it will interpret all but the last filename as sources, and the last one as a destination.

I think there's another source of confusion as well: when the shell expands a string containing a wildcard, it tries to match *the entire thing* to existing files and/or directories. So when you use `Volumes/Myshare/SourceVideo/$in1*/$in1.mov`, it looks for an already-existing file in a matching directory; AIUI the file isn't there yet, there's no match. What it does in that case is pass the raw (unexpanded) wildcard-containing string to `mv` as an argument, which looks for *that exact name*, doesn't find it, and gives you an error.

(BTW, should there be a "/" at the front of that pattern? I assume so below.)

If I understand the situation correctly, you might be able to use this:

```
mv -f /Volumes/Myshare/Processed/$in1.mov /Volumes/Myshare/SourceVideo/$in1*/
```

Since the filename isn't supplied in the second string, it doesn't look for existing files by that name, just directories with the right prefix; `mv` will automatically retain the filename from the source.

However, I'll echo @Sergio's warning about chaos from multiple matches. In this case, it won't overwrite files (well, it might, but for other reasons), but if it gets multiple matching target directories it'll move all but the last one into the last one (along with the file you meant to move). You say you're 100% certain this won't be a problem, but in my experience that means that there's at least a 50% chance that something you'd never have thought of will go ahead and make it happen anyway. For instance, is it possible that `$in1` could wind up empty, or contain a space, or...?

Speaking of spaces, I'd also recommend double-quoting all variable references. You want the variables inside double-quotes, but the wildcards outside them (or they won't be expanded), like this:

```
mv -f "/Volumes/Myshare/Processed/$in1.mov" "/Volumes/Myshare/SourceVideo/$in1"*/
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a shot. You're right, Murphy's Law always kicks in...Its quite possible an issue could arise. I'll try out your code just because i want it to work, but then i will consider a safer approach, such as tagging the filename with the foldername at the beginning of the chain, then its easy enough to find the matching folder at the end.